# Spark doesn't respect the case sensitivity of table

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem with case sensitivity in spark scala.
I want to read from a postgres table which contains some character in (uppercase) but by default spark convert the name into lowercase and I receive the error

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "textlogs" does not exist

```scala
val opts = Map(
  "url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/sparkdb",
  "dbtable" -> "TextLogs",
  "user" -> "admin",
  "password" -> "mypassword"
)
val df = spark
           .read
           .format("jdbc")
           .options(opts)
           .load
```

Is there a way to force spark to respect the case sensitivity ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Postgres, when you don't double quote object identifiers (like table name), they are treated as case insensitive. So this `TextLogs` actually equals to `textlogs`.

In order to have case sensitive object identifier, you need to double quote it. In your case, that would be `"TextLogs"`, so in your code you should just add escaped double quotes to table name:

```
val opts = Map(
  "url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/sparkdb",
  "dbtable" -> "\"TextLogs\"",
  "user" -> "admin",
  "password" -> "mypassword"
)
val df = spark
           .read
           .format("jdbc")
           .options(opts)
           .load
```